Supabase Row Level Security for Storage
I'm using supabase authentication and database for my project. Recently, I implemented this function which uploads files to supabase storage. it is pretty simple code.
if (files) {
        const supabase = await createClient();

        for (const file of files) {
          const fileExt = file.name.split(".").pop();
          const fileName = `${new Date().toISOString()}.${fileExt}`;
          const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
            .from("images")
            .upload(`products/${fileName}`, file);
          imageUrls.push(data?.fullPath);

          if (error) {
            console.error("Failed to upload image", error);
          }
        }
      }

it is working as expected. However, when I tried to implement security policy for my supabase, it did not work. I want users with ADMIN Roles to upload files to storage. I have USER table with role column that has either ADMIN or USER as value. Also, every user has supabase_auth_id which is authentication uid for the user. Currently, I have this policy that disallowing everyone to upload when it is supposed to disallow only signed in user without ADMIN roles.
(
  bucket_id = 'images'
)
AND
(
  auth.role() = 'authenticated'
)
AND
(
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM public."User"
    WHERE "User".supabase_auth_id = auth.uid()
      AND "User".role = 'ADMIN'
  )
)

I tried running the above script on my SQL Editor with static value for auth.uid(). For example:
SELECT *
FROM public."User"
WHERE supabase_auth_id = 'uid of some user' 
  AND role = 'ADMIN';

it returns an user. So, I put that uid in my security policy and signed in as that person, and tried uploading. But, it did not work. How can I implement this? And What am I doing wrong?
